# Run sbt integration test with extra settings

Tags: scala, sbt, integration-testing

I want to run the integration tests in sbt with an extra command line argument, that depends on an inputKey:

```
lazy val environmentTest = inputKey[Unit](
  "Run integration tests in a specific environment.")

lazy val environmentFile = Def.setting {
  (_: State) => fileParser(sourceDirectory.value / "it" / "conf")
}

environmentTest := {
  val envSettings = Seq(
    javaOptions in IntegrationTest += s"-Dconfig.file=${environmentFile.parsed.absolutePath}",
    (fork in IntegrationTest) := true
  )
  val projectState = state.value
  val envState = Project.extract(projectState).append(envSettings, projectState)
  Project.extract(envState).runAggregated((test in IntegrationTest), envState)
},
```

However, when I run the environmentTest input task, nothing happens. It does not run integration tests. it:test works fine.

How can I run the integration tests with an extra java option, that depends on an inputKey?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the Project.runTask:

```
environmentTest := {
  val envSettings = Seq(
    javaOptions in IntegrationTest += s"-Dconfig.file=${environmentFile.parsed.absolutePath}",
    (fork in IntegrationTest) := true
  )
  val envState = Project.extract(state.value).append(envSettings, state.value)
  Project.runTask((test in IntegrationTest), envState)
},
```